# Incoming Spam Mail in exim mail server

Tags: exim

My domain getting lot of spam mail like xxx@mydomain.com, yyy@mydomain.com. We don't have such user's but we getting mails like that.Also getting lot of bounce mails, How to control spam like this in exim mail server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use postmaster option

```
require verify = recipient
```

> This statement requires the recipient address to be verified; if
>   verification fails, the address is rejected.

See [Default Configuration](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-the_default_configuration_file.html)

You can also set some good acl rules to delay or block the host which sends the spam:

```
   deny  message         = Max $rcpt_fail_count failed recipients allowed
         condition       = ${if >{$rcpt_fail_count}{10} {1}}
         ! verify        = recipient
         delay           = ${eval: $rcpt_fail_count * 10}s
         log_message     = $rcpt_fail_count failed recipient attempts
```

See [FAQ](http://starcat.dp.ua/doc/exim4/FAQ-html/FAQ_7.html#TOC271)

Comment: Where i need to add this script. Please mention the path to edit.

Comment: In your config file, this is default `/etc/exim4/exim4.conf`. Most of the options are exist and need only to be uncommented. The `deny message` needs to be added after `begin acl`. You need also to put the message bevore any other acl passes another rule.

Comment: thank you. i will try by adding this code other mails wont affect right. we can receive all other mails without fails ?

Comment: :-) If you are the mail adm, then you need to know! So always double check if it works. The acl rule affects only emails with multiple unknown recipients, so it is confident that they are spam.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, this problem causes many people to react very quickly to [spam mail](https://www.mainfo.xyz/2022/12/what-you-should-know-to-combat-phishing.html).

Here's what you can do, verifying the recipient's address on the statement; Because if the verification fails, the address is rejected.

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note that your answer seems to reiterate what was already stated in the [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/123744/377345). You may want to consider expanding it so that the difference to that answer becomes more visible; otherwise it would be best placed as a comment to that answer (once you have sufficient reputation).